# Ionic App went live on app store - Socket now not working

Tags: ios, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io

I created an app using the Ionic Framework that has a live chat system in it. It uses a socket to pass messages back & forth. I'm using the angular-socket-io plugin. During development, everything works perfectly fine.

I released the app for both Android and iOS.

After downloading the app from the Android Marketplace, the socket works perfectly fine as expected.

The iOS version however does not connect to the socket when downloaded from the App Store. The app is not crashing and everything outside of socket stuff works fine. I deleted the app and ran it from my Mac with the code that we created the build from and it connects to the socket fine that way.

We are connecting to a Node.js script through HTTP. I have no idea if this makes any difference - just trying to provide you with as much information.

I'm wondering if anyone here has any speculation of what could cause the socket to not connect when downloaded from the App Store, but work fine when installed directly from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

After testing it much more, I noticed that it relied on the device token. The live app is not receiving the device token. I'm guessing this is due to the fact when we configured the app for Apple, the "Push Notifications" was turned off. When I replicated not having a device token in dev, the socket stopped connecting! I now have a starting  point to debug it.